# Ktorrent-like widgets in QTableView/QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qtgui

Is there any documentation about how to put a custom QWidget container (with other stuff like a layout, checkboxes, buttons etc) as a row in a QTableView/QTableWidget like is shown in the picture?

I'm browsing the source code of ktorrent to see how this is done.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: Ktorrent configuration widget as a QTableView row]

Answer (score 1):

For a [QTableWiget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) use

```
void QTableWidget::setCellWidget (int row, int column, QWidget  *widget)
```

In your case:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  // a composite widget with layouts and other stuff
};
setCellWidget(0, 0, new MyWidget);
```

In the case of a [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn) you have to define your custom delegate and set it (e.g.) for a certain column with:

```
void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn (int column, QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate)
```

[Check this out](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#details) for an example of a QProgressBar inside a table

Comment: And the multiple checkboxes, lineEdits and buttons? Those are part of the row, too O_o

Comment: You can put any QWidget as a table cell

Comment: I think I've seen how they do it. They put a widget directly  in the parent container of the row during the paint event. Is a bit tricky...